# Is there a way to set the initialItem for FixedExtentScrollController using a Future<int>?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I have a ListWheelScrollView, and I would like to set the index based on something I retrieve from a method (from Firebase), but it keeps giving me this error:

> The instance member 'currentWeek' can't be accessed in an initializer.
> Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different
> expression.

This is my code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
int currentWeek = getDueDate(); //method that returns an integer based on retrieval from database

    FixedExtentScrollController _scrollController =
        FixedExtentScrollController(initialItem: currentWeek);
```

Comment: I suggest you use a state management library such as GetX, Bloc, Provider-Riverpod or whatever you find more comfortable using. That way you can handle better this behavior. Or even using a StatefulWidget and setting the index to the value you like in the initState method.

Answer (score 0):

The initializer runs when the widget is initially created and added to the UI. Since loading data from Firestore takes some time, the value won't be available right away - and thus can't be used in the initializer.

The most common options for dealing with this:

- Give the index a default value to determine what to show while the data is loading.
- Show a different UI or don't show the UI element while the data is being loaded. For example, you could use a `FutureBuilder` for the index/data you load from Firestore. In its `build` you'd then either hide the UI element, or render another UI element (e.g. `Text("Loading...")` or `CircularProgressIndicator()`) while the data is loading.